# What happens when an LED burns out?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, diodes, semiconductors

When an LED is burned out, specifically which part is burned out?

Is it the semiconductor or the wires?

Can we use a burned out LED to generate electricity?

Comment: How would you use a damaged component to generate electricity? It's not clear how you think that could take place?

Comment: I guess you might be able to get energy out from burning the plastic it's housed in.

Comment: I've turned several Light Emitting Diodes into Dark Emiting Monodes, by putting in so much power that one leg falls off in the bang.

Comment: yes you can use the burned out LED to generate electricity .... amass several billion of burned out LEDs and use them as fuel in a coal fired power plant

Comment: Are we talking LED bare emitters here... or consumer product fixtures / lightbulb replacements based on LED tech?  Totally different answer.

Comment: @jsotola haha great joke!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica LED bare emitters

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, the idea is that when LED burns out if the needed construction for generating electricity is not damaged could we still get some electricity?

Comment: the thought was just hypothetical and wanted to know what exactly is damage in LED when it is burnt

Comment: and I am really thankful to everyone, thanx for ur answers

Comment: @ChynarGarlyyeva there's no such construction. It's absolutely not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry that didnt make it clear. I meant the semiconductor. Plz correct me if i am wrong: if the semiconductor is damaged then the p-n junction is destroyed and without the p-n junction is destroyed we cant generate electricity. And if the wire bond is damaged then we cant get the generated electricity. So i was wondering if there is any other thing that might burn or any way that we can still generate electricity?

Comment: the pn junction is the only functional thing in an LED. When you burn it, it's gone. Then you've got two wires that aren't connected anymore, or connected through a path of burned stuff that conducts slightly. There's nothing in there anymore that could "produce electricity".

Comment: @MarcusMüller Got it :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It could be the semiconductor or the wires.  [The answers here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408020/what-happens-to-the-semiconductor-in-an-led-when-it-is-given-voltage-that-it-can) should give you an idea of what goes wrong.  Sometimes the wires can be melted, sometimes the wire loses its connection to the semiconductor, and sometimes the semiconductor is damaged.

Regardless, you can't really generate much power from an LED.

I hooked up a blue LED to my voltmeter.  The voltmeter has in input impedance of 10 megaohms.  With the LED right up under a light bulb, I got 200 millivolts.

I then connected a 100k resistor across the LED and tried it again.  That got about 2 millivolts.  That's about 0.02 microamperes.

2 millivolts at 0.02 microamperes is about 0.04 nanowatts.

At that rate, you'd need 25 billion LEDs to get 1 watt of power.

It doesn't matter if the LED is broken or not - you ain't getting any useful amount of power out of it.

Comment: I'd argue that 2 mV at 20 nA is probably not the maximum power point, but i'm not sure i could keep a straight face while doing so.

Comment: @Hearth: :) :) :)

Comment: Only 25 billion, don't exaggerate!

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  Did I mangle a factor of 1000, or are we discussing the difference between ["long scale billion" and short scale billion" (British vs. American?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion)

Comment: thanx for ur answer

Comment: even though it is a small amount, can we generate electricity from a burnt LED?

Comment: @ChynarGarlyyeva: Most likely not.  The only time you would get anything out of the LED is when the wires are intact but the semiconductor is damaged.  You'd get even less power out of the LED than my calculations show.  The numbers I calculated are insane - and it doesn't matter.  If I missed by a factor of 1000, it is still too little to do anything with.  If I missed by a factor of 1 million, it is still to little to be useful.

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  Right.  Mangled a factor of 1000.  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: so if the wires are well, but the semiconductor is damaged, i can still get sth even tho very little

Comment: Most ways that the semiconductor can be damaged prevent it from conducting electricity, let alone generating it.

Comment: So it is not possible, right?

Comment: @ChynarGarlyyeva:  It is not possible,  It is not even really possible with **new** LEDs.

Comment: Are the British still using long scale billions? https://plainenglish.co.uk/campaigning/past-campaigns/budget/how-much-is-a-billion.html

Comment: thanks a lot everyone